# SQLite SUM() between several rows

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I need some help with the SUM feature in android app. I have a table that looks something like the following :

[image]

I have need to `SUM` Quantities between last two records Notes and last one record with Note. I need to sum Quantity of rows 31,32 and 33. It would return 90. I've tried

```
SELECT Sum(QUANTITY) FROM fuel_table WHERE NOTE!='' ORDER BY ID DESC
```

but it returns SUM of all quantities with note.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am inclined to phrase the question as:  sum the quantity from all rows that have one note "ahead" of them.  This suggests:

```
select sum(quantity)
from (select ft.*,
             (select count(*)
              from fuel_table ft2
              where ft2.note = 'Yes' and ft2.id >= ft.id
             ) as numNotesAhead
      from fuel_table ft
     ) ft
where numNotesAhead = 1;
```

Comment: It needs on "AS" before
ft
where numNotesAhead = 1;

Comment: @SimeonShopkin . . . According to the syntax diagram for SQLite (and my experience), the `as` is not necessary:  https://www.sqlite.org/syntax/table-or-subquery.html.

Answer (score 2):

```
WITH    max_id_with_note AS
        (
        SELECT  MAX(ID) AS max_id
        FROM    YourTable
        WHERE   IFNULL(note, '') <> ''
        )
,       previous_max_id_with_note AS
        (
        SELECT  max(ID) as max_id
        FROM    YourTable
        WHERE   IFNULL(note, '') <> ''
                AND ID < (SELECT max_id FROM max_id_with_note)
        )
SELECT  SUM(Quantity)
FROM    YourTable
WHERE   (SELECT max_id FROM previous_max_id_with_note)
        < ID and ID <= 
        (SELECT max_id FROM max_id_with_note)
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/07d49/8/0)

Comment: This code at SQL Fiddle returns (null) and broke my app. But this is the logic.

Comment: Good point, the order in the `where` clause was wrong, fixed now

Answer (score 0):

First select few ROW and from this selection query SUM(). In your case it looks like this:

```
Select SUM(t1.QUANTITY) FROM (SELECT QUANTITY from fuel_table WHERE NOTE!='' ORDER BY ID limit 2) as t1
```

Comment: This will works only in example, in real I don't know how much are rows between these with NOTE!='' :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your query as

```
SELECT Sum(QUANTITY) FROM fuel_table ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [sub query](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_sub_queries.htm) to get your `QUANTITY` in deceasing order by `ID` and `LIMIT 3` as you want last 3 row and put [SUM()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_useful_functions.htm) to the result quantity...

```
SELECT SUM(QUANTITY) FROM (SELECT QUANTITY FROM fuel_table ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

I created table like you have and test. Andomar had good idea but made few mistakes!

```
WITH    max_id_with_note AS
        (
        SELECT  MAX(ID) AS max_id
        FROM    fuel_table
        WHERE   Note <> ''
        )
,       previous_max_id_with_note AS
        (
        SELECT  max(ID) as max_id
        FROM    fuel_table
        WHERE   Note <> ''
                AND ID < (SELECT max_id FROM max_id_with_note)
        )
SELECT  SUM(Quantity)
FROM    fuel_table
WHERE          (SELECT max_id FROM previous_max_id_with_note)
        < id and id <= (SELECT max_id FROM max_id_with_note)
```